# How does spark decides column order when reading Parquet file

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have a directory in which I have 2 parquet files with same schema but columns order are different
I want to know how spark decides column order when reading the directory

**Input directory**
[image]

**Dataframe 1 while reading 1.parquet file**

[image]

**Dataframe 2 while reading 2.parquet file**

[image]

**When reading complete directory**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Column order depend of schema metadata , you can use a parquet viewer to inspect each file.

You can also provide a schema when reading parquet file to get all the time the same columns order.

```
val parquetSchema: Structype = new structype()
.add("id",IntegerType,true)
.add("login",StringType,true)

spark.read.schema(parquetSchema).parquet(...)
```